# Convert Unix timestamp value to human readable python

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I have a Unix timestamp which value is `1502878840`. This Unix timestamp value can be converted to human readable like `Aug 16, 2017 10:20:40`.
I have 2 following python code to convert `1502878840` to `Aug 16, 2017 10:20:40`. Both of them give a same result (`Aug 16, 2017 10:20:40`)

1. First method
   `utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(1502878840)`
2. Second method
   `utc = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=1502878840)`

Could anyone answer me 2 following questions.
1. The result of 2 methods are same. But at the logic view point of Python code, is there any case that may cause the difference in result?
I ask this question because I see most of the python code use First method.
2. As I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the Unix time will have a problem on 19 January, 2038 03:14:08 GMT.
I run a timestamp which has a date after 19.Jan, 2038 (`2148632440`- `Feb 01, 2038 10:20:40`). The result is as follows
First method: `ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t`
Second method: `2038-02-01 10:20:40`
Question is: Can I use Second method to overcome the problem of "Year 2038 problem"?

Comment: First method needs to be `utcfromtimestamp()`.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I read manual of datetime again. It is better if we use `utcfromtimestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

> fromtimestamp() may raise OverflowError, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C localtime() or gmtime() functions, and OSError on localtime() or gmtime() failure. **It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038.** Note that on non-POSIX systems that include leap seconds in their notion of a timestamp, **leap seconds are ignored** by fromtimestamp(), and then it’s possible to have two timestamps differing by a second that yield identical datetime objects. See also utcfromtimestamp().

The second solution solves your problem:

```
utc = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=1502878840)
```

Comment: The `timedelta` documentation mentions a limit of `999999999` days. That's less than 3M years. The planet earth may last much longer than that.

Comment: @Gribouillis Good news, and Python may survive to that 

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE : Thank you for your answer. By this answer, I have a method to overcome the Year 2038 problem.

Comment: @Gribouillis: Thank you for your information. Actually, my intention is to solve Year 2038 problem firstly. I know that `timedelta` has a limitation as your mention (3M years), but for a very far future like that, we can not sure anything. The hardware running python program can running until to the next 3M years? I see some RTC chip also limits their correct operation until 2099 :).